# What are the conditions for ios to cache BLE Services and Characteristics?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I have read that ios is caching Services and Characteristics of a BLE peripheral when I disconnect and then reconnect to the same device (After those Services and Characteristics have been discovered of course). So the lenghty process of rediscovering is not necessary and I can directly write or read to those Characteristics after a reconnect.

In this thread:
[Is there a way to discover BLE peripheral service faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404503/is-there-a-way-to-discover-ble-peripheral-service-faster)
it is said that Services and Characteristics are cached if the connection is encrypted. Also, in WWDC 2013 Session 702 it says Services and Characteristics are cached but the conditions are not specified.

What are the conditions for ios to cache BLE Services and Characteristics? Can someone verify that just an encrypted connection is needed?