# iOS - BLE Scanning on background freezes randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-process, core-bluetooth

**UPDATE 14/08 - 3 - Found the real solution:**

You can check out the solution in the answers below !

**UPDATE 16/06 - 2 - May be the solution :**

As Sandy Chapman suggested in comments in his answer, i'm able now to retrieve my peripheral at the start of a scan by using this method :

```
- (NSArray<CBPeripheral *> * nonnull)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray<NSUUID *> * nonnull)identifiers
```

I'm actually trying to make it work by getting my peripheral back at the start of a scan and launching a connection (even if it's not in range) when i need it. iOS will keep it alive until it finds the device i'm looking for.

**Please also note that there might be a bug in iOS 8.x that keep an app with debug build from scanning (disappearing callbacks as i get) from time to time if there is another app in background with release build that is using Bluetooth.**

**UPDATE 16/06 :**

So i checked with retrievePeripheralsWithServices if any device was connected while i'm starting the scan. 
When i get the bug, i launch the app and the first thing i do in

```
- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is to check the size of the returned array. It's always 0, each time i get the bug. The bug can happen also if my device hasn't made any connection earlier in the current run. I'm also able to see my device advertising and trigger a command with a second device while i got the bug with another device.

**UPDATE 10/06 :**

- I left my app running the entire night to check if there wasn't any memory leak or massive resource usage, here are my result after ~12-14 hours of running in the background. Memory/CPU usage are exactly the same as they were when i left. It leads me to think my app hasn't any leak that could lead iOS to close it to get back memory/CPU usage.

[image: Resource usage analysis]

**UPDATE 08/06 :**

- Note that it's not an advertising issue since our BLE device is consistently powered, and we used the strongest BLE electronic card we could found.
- It's also not an issue with iOS detection timing in background. I waited for a very long time(20~30min) to be sure that wasn't this issue.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm currently working on an app that handle communication with a BLE device. One of my constraint is that i must connect to this device only when i have to send a command or read data. I must disconnect as soon as possible when it's done, to allow other potential users to do the same.

One of the features of the app is the following :

- Users can enable an automatic command while the app is in the background. This automatic command triggers if the device hasn't been detected within 10 minutes.
- My app scans until it finds my BLE device.
- In order to keep it awake when i need it, i'm restarting the scan each time, because of the CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey option ignorance.
- When it's detected, i'm checking if the last detection was more than 10 minutes ago. If that's the case, i connect to the device and then write into the characteristic corresponding to the service i need.

The goal is to trigger this device when user come in range. It may happen a few minutes after being out of range such as a few hours, it depends on my users habits.

Everything is working fine this way, but sometimes (it seems like happening at random times), the scan sort of "freezes". My process is done well, but after a couple of time, i see my app scanning, but my didDiscoverPeripheral: call back is never called, even if my testing device is right in front of my BLE device. Sometimes it may take a while to detect it, but here, nothing happens after a couple of minutes.

I was thinking that iOS may have killed my app to claim back memory, but when i turn off and on Bluetooth, **centralManagerDidUpdateState:** is called the right way. If my app where killed, it shouldn't be the case right ?
If i open my app, the scan is restarted and it's coming back to life.
I also checked that iOS doesn't shutdown my app after 180 seconds of activity, but that's not the case because it's working well after this amount of time.

I've set up my .plist to have the right settings (**bluetooth-central** in **UIBackgroundModes**). My class managing all BLE processing is stored in my **AppDelegate** as a singleton accessible through all of my app. I've also tested to switch where i'm creating this object. Currently i'm creating it in the **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method. I tried to put it in my **AppDelegate** **init:** but the scans fails every time while i'm in background if i do so.

I don't know which part of my code i could show you to help you better understand my process. Here is some samples that might help. Please note that " **AT_appDelegate** " is a maccro in order to access my **AppDelegate**.

```
// Init of my DeviceManager class that handles all BLE processing
- (id) init {
   self = [super init];

   // Flags creation
   self.autoConnectTriggered = NO;
   self.isDeviceReady = NO;
   self.connectionUncomplete = NO;
   self.currentCommand = NONE;
   self.currentCommand_index = 0;

   self.signalOkDetectionCount = 0; // Helps to find out if device is at a good range or too far
   self.connectionFailedCount = 0;  // Helps in a "try again" process if a command fails

   self.main_uuid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:MAINSERVICE_UUID];
   self.peripheralsRetainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   self.lastDeviceDetection = nil;

   // Ble items creation
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.onset.corebluetooth.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
   self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue];

[self startScanning];
return self;
}

   // The way i start the scan
- (void) startScanning {

   if (!self.isScanning && self.centralManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

    CLS_LOG(@"### Start scanning ###");
    self.isScanning = YES;

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!self.isBackground] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[self.main_uuid] options:options];

    });
  }
  }

  // The way i stop and restart the scan after i've found our device. Contains    some of foreground (UI update) process that you can ignore
  - (void) stopScanningAndRestart: (BOOL) restart {

  CLS_LOG(@"### Scanning terminated ###");
  if (self.isScanning) {

    self.isScanning = NO;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self.centralManager stopScan];
  });

  // Avoid clearing the connection when waiting for notification (remote + learning)

     if (!self.isWaitingNotifiy && !self.isSynchronizing && self.currentCommand == NONE ) {
        // If no device found during scan, update view

        if (self.deviceToReach == nil && !self.isBackground) {

            // Check if any connected devices last
            if (![self isDeviceStillConnected]) {
               CLS_LOG(@"--- Device unreachable for view ---");

            } else {

                self.isDeviceInRange = YES;
                self.deviceToReach = AT_appDelegate.user.device.blePeripheral;
            }

            [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];       

        }

        // Reset var
        self.deviceToReach = nil;
        self.isDeviceInRange = NO;
        self.signalOkDetectionCount = 0;

        // Check if autotrigger needs to be done again - If time interval is higher enough,
        // reset autoConnectTriggered to NO. If user has been away for <AUTOTRIGGER_INTERVAL>
        // from the device, it will trigger again next time it will be detected.

        if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [self.lastDeviceDetection timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > AUTOTRIGGER_INTERVAL) {

            CLS_LOG(@"### Auto trigger is enabled ###");
            self.autoConnectTriggered = NO;
        }
    }
}


   if (restart) {
    [self startScanning];
   }
  }

  // Here is my detection process, the flag "isInBackground" is set up each    time the app goes background
  - (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

CLS_LOG(@"### : %@ -- %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);
BOOL deviceAlreadyShown = [AT_appDelegate isDeviceAvailable];

// If current device has no UUID set, check if peripheral is the right one
// with its name, containing his serial number (macaddress) returned by
// the server on remote adding

NSString *p1 = [[[peripheral.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Extel " withString:@""] uppercaseString];

NSString *p2 = [AT_appDelegate.user.device.serial uppercaseString];

if ([p1 isEqualToString:p2]) {
    AT_appDelegate.user.device.scanUUID = peripheral.identifier;
}

// Filter peripheral connection with uuid
if ([AT_appDelegate.user.device.scanUUID isEqual:peripheral.identifier]) {
    if (([RSSI intValue] > REQUIRED_SIGNAL_STRENGTH && [RSSI intValue] < 0) || self.isBackground) {
        self.signalOkDetectionCount++;
        self.deviceToReach = peripheral;
        self.isDeviceInRange = (self.signalOkDetectionCount >= REQUIRED_SIGNAL_OK_DETECTIONS);

        [peripheral setDelegate:self];
        // Reset blePeripheral if daughter board has been switched and there were
        // not enough time for the software to notice connection has been lost.
        // If that was the case, the device.blePeripheral has not been reset to nil,
        // and might be different than the new peripheral (from the new daugtherboard)

       if (AT_appDelegate.user.device.blePeripheral != nil) {
            if (![AT_appDelegate.user.device.blePeripheral.name isEqualToString:peripheral.name]) {
                AT_appDelegate.user.device.blePeripheral = nil;
            }
        }

        if (self.lastDeviceDetection == nil ||
            ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [self.lastDeviceDetection timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > AUTOTRIGGER_INTERVAL)) {
            self.autoConnectTriggered = NO;
        }

        [peripheral readRSSI];
        AT_appDelegate.user.device.blePeripheral = peripheral;
        self.lastDeviceDetection = [NSDate date];

        if (AT_appDelegate.user.device.autoconnect) {
            if (!self.autoConnectTriggered && !self.autoTriggerConnectionLaunched) {
                CLS_LOG(@"--- Perform trigger ! ---");

                self.autoTriggerConnectionLaunched = YES;
                [self executeCommand:W_TRIGGER onDevice:AT_appDelegate.user.device]; // trigger !
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    if (deviceAlreadyShown) {
        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

if (self.isBackground && AT_appDelegate.user.device.autoconnect) {
    CLS_LOG(@"### Relaunch scan ###");
    [self stopScanningAndRestart:YES];
}
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many many tries, i may finally have found the real solution.

FYI, i had many talks with an engineer at Apple (via Technical Support). He led me in two ways :

- Checking that **Core Bluetooth preservation / restoration** state are correctly implemented. You will be able to found a few threads about it on stack overflow like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529685/core-bluetooth-state-preservation-and-restoration-not-working-cant-relaunch-ap) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897891/core-bluetooth-state-restoration). You will also found apple documentation useful here : [Core Bluetooth Background Processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5).
- Checking connections parameters implemented in my Bluetooth device, such as : **Connection Interval**, **Minimum and Maximum connection interval**, **Slave latency** and **Connection timeout**. There is much information in [Apple Bluetooth Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf)

The real solution may take part in these elements. I added and corrected things while i was searching to clean this bug. But the thing that made it work (i tested it for around 4-5h and it didn't froze at all) was about **dispatch_queue**.

What i did before :

```
// Initialisation
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.onset.corebluetooth.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:RESTORE_KEY}];

// Start scanning
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[self.main_uuid] options:options];
});

// Stop scanning
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   [self.centralManager stopScan];
});
```

What i'm doing now :

```
// Initialisation
self.bluetoothQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.onset.corebluetooth.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:self.bluetoothQueue options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:RESTORE_KEY}];

// Start scanning
dispatch_async(self.bluetoothQueue, ^{
   [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[self.main_uuid] options:options];
});

// Stop scanning
dispatch_async(self.bluetoothQueue, ^{
   [self.centralManager stopScan];
});
```

Please note that i added this line to my DeviceManager.h (my main Ble class) :

```
@property (atomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t bluetoothQueue;
```

As you can see it was a little messed up :)

So now i'm able to scan as long as needed. Thanks for your help ! I hope it might help someone one day.

Answer (score 3):

In your sample code, it doesn't look like you're calling either of these methods on your CBCentralManager:

`- (NSArray<CBPeripheral *> * nonnull)retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray<CBUUID *> * nonnull)serviceUUIDs`

`- (NSArray<CBPeripheral *> * nonnull)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray<NSUUID *> * nonnull)identifiers`

It's possible that you're in a state where you're waiting on a `didDiscoverPeripheral` that will never come because the system is already connected. After instantiating your CBCentralManager, first check to see if your peripheral is already connected by calling one of these methods.

The start-up flow for my central manager which uses state restoration is as follows:

1. Check for available peripherals from the restoration state (not needed in your case).
2. Check for peripherals discovered from a previous scan (I keep these in an array of available peripherals).
3. Check for connected peripherals (using methods mentioned above).
4. Begin scanning if none of the above returned a peripheral.

One additional thing tip that you may have already discovered: iOS will cache the characteristics and UUIDs advertised by a peripheral. If these change, the only way to clear the cache is to toggle bluetooth off and on in the iOS system settings.

Comment: Hello, it might be something in that way. In my process, i disconnect from the peripheral after each command. However my manager class is very heavy so i may have missed something. I try your solution and i will keep you in touch of my result (i will try to do this before "bounty giving" timer runs out)

Comment: Also notice that i also keep my detected peripherals in an array. I initialize this array each time i start a new scan (each 8 seconds ~)

Comment: So i checked with retrievePeripheralsWithServices. When i get the bug, i launch the app and the first thing i do in `- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` is to check the size of the returned array. It's always 0, each time i get the bug :/ The bug can happen also if my device hasn't made any connection earlier in the current run. I will try to do the check just after the scan started

Comment: @Jissay: Just to confirm that this definitely isn't your peripheral, what happens when you launch your app on a second device and try to connect to the peripheral? Is it able to connect? If not, then maybe advertising hasn't been re-started on your peripheral.

Comment: Yes i'm able to see my device advertising after i got the freeze (with both another iOS device and Android device), i can also trigger a command (connect / write on a characteristic / disconnect).

Comment: @Jissay, can you try using the `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method as well? Basically, that method should return any previously connect devices and you should then be able to initiate a connection to said device even if you've not received an advertisement yet.

Comment: Indeed you're right ! I'm able to get my peripheral while i'm starting the scan. My issue here will be to send the trigger when it's needed (i won't trigger until the device hasn't been detected for at least 10 min), but i will probably use a local notification (NSTimer won't stay alive in the background). I read somewhere that if you try to connect a peripheral that isn't in range yet, iOS keep this try alive until you find the requested peripheral. Do you know if there is any condition to make it work ?

Comment: @Jissay: I believe as long as you have the `bluetooth-central` background mode set in your Info.plist file, your app should be woken up as soon as the peripheral comes in range. See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80681/discussion-between-jissay-and-sandy-chapman).

Comment: You can check out the actual solution, i found it after a few debug sessions ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the Bluetooth device you are trying to pair with, some of them have a low advertising rate, this is usually done to save battery-life. The first thing I'd check is how often the BLE device is configured to advertise.

This may even be related to the iOS device not scanning as frequently as other devices, as covered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404503/is-there-a-way-to-discover-ble-peripheral-service-faster).

Comment: Our device is continuously powered, (so we haven't any battery issues to deal with), we used the best card we could found to avoid this type of issues. I've already seen the post you mentioned and to test it out, i waited a really looong time (20-30min) to see if my device will be detected by the scan. The answer is no. I agree on the fact that iOS could be very slow to detect a BLE device, but 20 min seems to high to be true !

Comment: Have you confirmed there isn't a Bluetooth issue in the iOS version you are using? In their pursuit for power savings sometimes they break things like BLE/WiFi. I remember reading about something along those lines recently in iOS8. Found a link: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/ios-8-3-users-facing-issues-bluetooth-gps-receivers-1496526

Comment: I've tested with many version of iOS 8 (8.1, 8.2, 8.3), but i haven't tested it yet on iOS 7+ (to confirm it's a bug from iOS 8 and/or above). As soon as i get an iOS 7 device, i will be able to tell and update my question (probably tomorrow). I will investigate in that way